# LaTeX: Avoid the increase of text row height due to inline math

Tags: latex, spacing, row-height

In the following example code the height of the second row of text increases due to the presence of the inline math formula:

```
\documentclass{article}
\linespread{0.9}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, 
felis. $A_n^{\{x\}}$ Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu 
libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can this be avoided without changing the general linespread, so that the height of the second row is identical to that of the other rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `\smash` the inline math formula:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

% Default layout/spacing
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, 
felis. $A_n^{\{x\}}$ Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu 
libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. 

% Smashed inline math
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, 
felis. \smash{$A_n^{\{x\}}$} Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu 
libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. 

\end{document}
```

However, it's obvious that tall [deep] inline expressions may butt into descenders [ascenders] of the line above [below].